# JavaFx sending a temporary excel file as an attachment in mail

Tags: java, excel, file, javafx

I want to send a excel file as an attachment in mail
When i use the a physical file everything is good but when i use it as a temporary file i got this exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;        
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 2019-03-02.xls (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
```

when creating the temporary file the following code is used :

```
//....
    try {//create temp file here
            file = File.createTempFile(today,".xlsx");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Writer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                workbook.write(fileOut);
//.....
```

but when i use a normal file like this it works very fine :

```
try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(today+".xlsx")) {
            workbook.write(fileOut);
```

any solutions ?

or any suggestions how to send an excel file without saving it ?

**EDIT :** here is the full exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: 2019-03-02.xls (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:625)
    at rapport.rapportc.sendMail(rapportc.java:113)
    at rapport.rapportc.envoyer(rapportc.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 2019-03-02.xls (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:97)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:305)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1350)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:845)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:361)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:85)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1350)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1683)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:585)
    ... 60 more
```

**EDIT2 :** here is the function i use to send an email with attachment

```
private void sendMail(){

        try{
        String host ="smtp.gmail.com" ;
        String user = "send@gmail.com";
        String pass = "pwd";
        String to = "recieve@gmail.com";
        String from = "send@gmail.com";
        String subject = "sending day : "+today; // today is a string variable for today's date
        String messageText = "msg";
        boolean sessionDebug = false;

        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

        java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject(subject); msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(messageText);
        Multipart emailContent = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textBodyPart.setText("");
        MimeBodyPart excelAttach = new MimeBodyPart();
        String path = today+".xls"; // here where i put the excel file to be send
        excelAttach.attachFile(path);
        emailContent.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
        emailContent.addBodyPart(excelAttach);
        msg.setContent(emailContent);

        Transport transport=mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, user, pass);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("message send successfully");

    }catch(IOException | MessagingException ex)
    {
        alert.alert.showErrorMessage(ex);
        return;
    }
}
```

**Ps :** when i send a physical file everything works fine

i want to send the excel file without saving it either with temporary file or another way !

Comment: Please edit your question and show the full, unaltered stack trace of your IOException.  The IOException you are showing us could not be generated from use of a temporary file, because temporary files are always created in the system’s temporary files directory (if no explicit directory parameter is given).

Comment: @VGR i have put the full exception , so what i get from your comment is that i need to specify the full path for the temporary file when i send it  ? in my My sendMail function !

Comment: Please also show the code which builds the Message you are sending, including the code which attaches the file to a body part.

Comment: @VGR i have put the sendMail function and commented the line where i put the excel file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a more informative exception message if you change this:

```
excelAttach.attachFile(path);
```

to this:

```
excelAttach.attachFile(new File(path).getAbsolutePath());
```

The problem is that you have made two incorrect assumptions about the behavior of File.createTempFile.

All operating systems create a temporary file using a set of random characters, to guarantee that the file is unique.  When you do `file = File.createTempFile(today, ".xlsx")`, you are *not* creating a file named `2019-03-02.xls`, but rather a file with a name like `/tmp/2019-03-02jxl9BZ.xls`.  So, when you attach `2019-03-02.xls`, you are attaching a nonexistent file, which is what the exception is telling you.

The second problem is that you are passing a *relative filename.*  A relative filename is always resolved relative to the current directory of the Java process.  This means `2019-03-02.xls` is the same as `/home/vgr/2019-03-02.xls`, if you happen to be running from the /home/vgr directory.  But temporary files are never created in that location, so, again, you are trying to attach a file that doesn’t exist.  (Relative files are not a Java concept;  they have been a fundamental part of operating systems for decades.)

The solution is to retain `file` in a field (if you aren’t doing so already), and pass that to the attachFile method:

```
excelAttach.attachFile(file);
```

Comment: I used the second one and it worked perfectly worked and thanks a lot for the lesson , a have a some questions if you could help 1-  when that temporary file will be deleted ? 2- can i rename it before i send it ? thanks again

Comment: The temporary file is yours to do with as you please.  You can certainly rename it or move it if you wish.  Many operating systems clean their temporary directories upon rebooting.  If you wish to delete it yourself, you can do that in a [shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

Comment: even after rebooting the files are still in the C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp directory

Comment: Other operating systems clear the temporary directory, but [windows does not](https://superuser.com/questions/296824/when-is-a-windows-users-temp-directory-cleaned-out).  So it’s best to delete the file in a shutdown hook.  You can also use [deleteOnExit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29).